# Merge images by list python

Tags: python, list, image, path

there is a big list containing paths to images:

```
list= ['home/1.png','home/2.png', ...,'home/100.png']
```

How to combine them sequentially horizontally?

Comment: what does "combine sequentially horizontally" means?

Comment: What do you mean by merging images? Another recommendation is to not use "list" as a variable name, since it already references to a builtin.

Comment: combine sequentially horizontally means axis=1

Comment: what to use instead of a list? i need to connect images one by one horizontally

Comment: Take a look at [`np.hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem!

list_= ['home/1.png','home/2.png', ...,'home/100.png']

```
from PIL import Image

images = [Image.open(x) for x in list_]
widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))

total_width = sum(widths)
max_height = max(heights)

new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))

x_offset = 0
for im in images:    
    new_im.paste(im, (x_offset,0))
    x_offset += im.size[0]

new_im.save('/test.png')
```